# Inbound Static Fixed IP Address Proxy for App Engine or other Cloud Environments

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-app-engine, proxy, firewall

App Engine and some other cloud platforms are using a wide range of IP addresses which makes it tricky for those who have firewall restrictions.

We have customers who wants to use our services but they can only send requests to known IP addresses.

How do I set up a fixed IP-address proxy for http/https forwarding to a cloud service?

Comment: what's the question?

Comment: How provide a fixed ip address for Google App Engine and others?

Answer (score -1):

Here is a simple recipe on how to write an inbound proxy for your cloud services.

Requirements: Access to a machine with a fixed IP and with Node.js installed.

The Node script below is all you need

1) Cut and paste into a file and execute

2) Change "my.server.com"

3) Change the SSL certificates path, instruction on how to create them below

```
var
    fs = require('fs'),
    url = require('url'),
    http = require('http'),
    https = require('https');

var https_options = {
    key: fs.readFileSync('/path/ssl_certificate/key.pem'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync('/path/ssl_certificate/cert.pem')
};

function http_forward(request, response) {
    'use strict';
    var
        target_host_options = {},
        target_url_obj = url.parse('https://my.server.com' + request.url),
        target_host_obj = https,
        target_host_request;

    target_host_options.hostname = target_url_obj.hostname;
    target_host_options.path = target_url_obj.path || '/';

    if (target_url_obj.auth) {
        target_host_options.path = target_url_obj.auth;
    }

    target_host_options.agent = false;  //Disable socket pooling
    target_host_options.method = request.method;
    target_host_options.headers = request.headers;
    delete target_host_options.headers.host; //Necessary
    target_host_options.headers['X-Proxy-Client-Ip'] = request.connection.remoteAddress;


    target_host_request = target_host_obj.request(target_host_options, function (target_host_response) {
        target_host_response.resume();

        response.writeHead(target_host_response.statusCode, target_host_response.headers);
        target_host_response.pipe(response);
    });

    target_host_request.on('error', function (err) {
        response.writeHead(400, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
        response.write('PROXY target_host_request error\n');
        response.write(JSON.stringify(err));
        response.end();
    });


    request.pipe(target_host_request);
}

http.createServer(http_forward).listen(8080);
https.createServer(https_options, http_forward).listen(8443);
console.log('Inbound_proxy ..starting...');
```

If you dont have a SSL certificate: Below how you create one using linux/ubuntu

```
$ openssl genrsa -out key.pem
$ openssl req -new -key key.pem -out csr.pem
$ openssl x509 -req -days 9999 -in csr.pem -signkey key.pem -out cert.pem
$ rm csr.pem
```

Comment: this does not answer the question

Comment: I have tested this proxy script with Node v0.12.7 and v4.0.0

Comment: The proxy is listening  on port 8080 (http) and 8443 (https), just to avoid possible security restrictions